# Webpack fails to transpile module imported from npm package

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have created an npm package with that `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-3"]
}
```

and this part in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?/,
      include: APP_DIR,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
  ]
]
```

the source code includes stuff like: `{ ...oldObject }`, so newes ES6 Features and it compiles fine.

However, in another project, where I actually need that package, i have that in the `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "r2d2": "git+ssh://git@xxxxxxxx:~/r2d2"
}
```

the `.babelrc` includes:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env",
    "stage-3"
  ]
}
```

and the `webpack.config.js` part is the same. **But** if I try to compile from here, webpack throws that error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/r2d2/src/js/main.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (80:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|           .keys(Actions)
|           .reduce((result, key) => ({
|             ...result,
|             [key]: Actions[key](id)
|           }), {})
@ ./src/js/main.js 5:23-51
```

Why is that, and what can I do to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include: APP_DIR,
```

specifically says to only compile things inside `APP_DIR`.

```
./node_modules/r2d2/src/js/main.js
```

is not in that folder, so it doesn't get compiled.

The easiest fix would be to expand your loader config to

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?/,
    include: [
      APP_DIR,
      __dirname + "/node_modules/r2d2",
    ],
    loader: 'babel-loader'
  }
]
```

Comment: Removing `include` is a bad idea because then you are running _every_ file in your project through Babel, and random stuff in `node_modules` could be broken because `env` transformed them in ways they didn't expect. If you're going to compile a node module, it should be a specific one you've opted into. Even if it works now, a random dependency could publish a new version at any time that could break.

Comment: Thanks for that, too! I will have an eye on it…